# style for mouse hovering of asp.net menu control

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have an asp.net menu control in my application.Each node is an image of different color and the styles of the subnodes are set in the sitemap.How can I set the mouse hovering of back ground color for each subnode which is of different color?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <asp:menu id="NavigationMenu" runat="server">
    <dynamichoverstyle backcolor="LightSkyBlue"
      forecolor="Black"/>
  </asp:menu>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.dynamichoverstyle.aspx

Comment: I have to set different color for each menu item.So what you said doesnt work in my case!

Comment: Sorry then I think your only option is to use JavaScript or ditch the menu control.